# Live range (interval) analysis on llvm

Tags: llvm, bitcode, register-allocation

How does llvm compute the live ranges (intervals) of its temporaries?
Here is an example C file:

```
$ cat main.c
int main()
{
    int i = 200;
    int j = 300;
    while (j)
    {
        i=i+1;
        j=j-1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I execute the following commands, and then examine both `main.ll` and `main.mem2reg.ll`. I'm probably wrong, but it looks like computing live ranges is much easier on `main.ll`(?) is `mem2reg` an essential pass when computing the live range? or is it a nice-to-have for certain optimizations?

```
$ clang -c -emit-llvm -O0 main.c -o main.bc
$ opt -instnamer main.bc -o main.bc
$ opt -mem2reg main.bc -o main.mem2reg.bc
$ llvm-dis main.bc
$ llvm-dis main.mem2reg.bc
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform live range analysis, you may have to know some knowledge about [liveness analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_variable_analysis) or you can checkout [cranelift's annotation](https://github.com/CraneStation/cranelift/blob/8033deda3ac152d0b95bb0ad80b419625c3f0d58/lib/cretonne/src/regalloc/liveness.rs#L1-L176). 
Pass `mem2reg` just transform the IR into SSA form, but for live range analysis, I think this is not necessary.

I have an simple implementation of live variable analysis with llvm, please checkout my GitHub repo: https://github.com/lijiansong/clang-llvm-tutorial/tree/master/live-variable-analysis